# Django Rest not working with session authentication

Tags: python, django, session, django-rest-framework

I am using django Rest framework with following code

```
authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,
                          JSONWebTokenAuthentication,
                          )
```

and it settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
```

When i visit the authenticated url then it says Authrization credentails not provided . Then i click on login.

The problem is after successfully logging in i still see authorization credentails not provided . I have to refresh page 2-3 times and then i am authenticated.

I don't know whats the issue

Comment: How are you accessing the url?  REST is intended for use by API calls, not by a person sitting at a browser.

Comment: @JohnGordon i am visiting the url by browser via Django Rest API browser. I know it will be used by api calls and thats working fine . but just for initial testing , i want to use browser

Comment: Perhaps your browser is caching the original non-authenticated response?  See if your browser has a setting to disable all page caching.

Comment: @JohnGordon . I have used that  in previous applications as well. It never did like that . I never had to do anything in browser to fix that

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

This will get you right. I've been in a long war with drf sessions vs tokens. I think I finally made a breakthrough. I know you could just use query parameters with a get request, but that feels wrong to me. I need this to get a svelte/next frontend to work with the django rest backend. I tried plenty of ways to make the default drf auth work. I decided to hunker down and make my own authentication views. With this method what you need to do is GET the login view and immediately POST the login view. The GET sets the csrf token and the POST logins in the user with the session cookie.

#### Highlights

- Frontend must GET to acquire the csrf cookie.
- Frontend must follow with POST to acquire the session cookie.
- AllowAny required since nobody is logged in yet.

###### Debate

- Yes you could place the POST logic inside of the GET and use query parameters thus nullifying the csrf requirement, but what fun is that?

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate

# Create your views here.


class LoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request):
        return Response('OK')

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed()
        login(request, user)
        return Response('OK')
```